# How to click just some buttons of a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do the following:

[image]

I have the positions 1 to 16, and the names of the people. Each number belongs to each person:

> POSITION 1 is for ROBERT, number 3 is for JULIA, etc

The `ASK` button for `ROBERT` is exactly the same as the one for `JULIA` - it has the same identifier number (or variable, idk how it's called in javascript), and it has the same function, except it messages a different person.

> So, how do I click `ASK` automatically just for those whose name ends in `KE`?

I found a script that does a part of what I need, and I believe that with this script, plus a `counter` I will achieve what I need.

> However, how do I unify these two : the `counter` with the below code?

I can't find the way/logic to do it.

**Code:**

```
    function clickAsk(){
      $('button.ASK').on(
        'click', function(){
          console.log('You clicked',$(this).html())
        }
      );
      $('button.ASK').each(
        function(index){
            setTimeout(()=>{$(this).click()},index*1000);
        }
      );
    }
    setTimeout(clickAsk,850)
```

This clicks every `ASK` button, first the 1st, then the 2nd, then the 3rd, etc. But I only need to click `ASK` for the persons whose name ends in `KE` ( i.e. `2.JAKE and 4.Spike` )

PS: Just in case, the Timeout is fine, i will use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an id but I find it better to use the data selector.

```js
$('.user').each(function () {
var $this = $(this);
$this.on("click", function () {
alert($(this).data('users'));
var str = $this.text();
if (str.match(/ke$/)){
    alert($this.text());
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="user" data-users="user1" >Mike</button>
<br>
<button class="user" data-users="user2" >Jake</button>
<br>
<button class="user" data-users="user3" >Henry</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a `data` attrib to every button, which holds the name of the person who the button belongs to:

```
<button class="user" data-name="Robert" value="ASK">
<button class="user" data-name="Julia" value="ASK">
etc...
```

Then you can use the following code to check for endings:

```
$('.user').each(function (i, o) {
    if ($(o).data('name').endsWith('KE')) {
        $(o).click();
    }
});
```